# How can I switch to the `[No Name]` buffer

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

As title. Is it possible to change the current buffer by vimscript to the (only) `[No Name]` buffer?

I need these tools:

- an API to return all (loaded) buffers
- loop through each of them

  - if the buffer is a `No Name`-buffer, then record its buffer number
- an API to edit that buffer from the current window.

I put emphasis on "the only" is that what I want to do is to keep only one `No Name`-buffer, so there won't be many `No Name`-buffers that spam out there. To do so my idea is that whenever I want to open a new `No Name`-buffer use a script to check if there is one: if so switch to it, if not then really create one.

Comment: Use vim however you want, but to me this would be odd. When I run `:new` or `:enew`, I want a _new_ buffer (not to automatically re-use an existing one). A `:Scratch` command that re-uses the same buffer might be interesting, though.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Just to provide context: I just created a plugin (while in Lua). In the implementation I need to use `:enew` to substitute the current buffer to a `No Name`, while I don't want to be spammed by many `No Name` buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Lua version:

> - an API to return all (loaded) buffers
> - loop through each of them
>
>   - if the buffer is a `No Name`-buffer, then record its buffer number

```lua
local function is_no_name_buf(buf)
  return
    vim.api.nvim_buf_is_loaded(buf)
    and vim.api.nvim_buf_get_option(buf, 'buflisted')
    and vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(buf) == ''
    and vim.api.nvim_buf_get_option(buf, 'buftype') == ''
    and vim.api.nvim_buf_get_option(buf, 'filetype') == ''
end

local all_no_name = vim.tbl_filter(is_no_name_buf, vim.api.nvim_list_bufs())
```

> an API to edit that buffer from the current window.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_win_set_buf(win, buf_to_put)
```

Answer (score 2):

> an API to return all (loaded) buffers

`:h getbufinfo()`

> loop through each of them

`:h filter()`

> if the buffer is a No Name-buffer

```
:echo empty(bufname(N))
:echo empty(getbufinfo(N)[0].name)
```

> an API to edit that buffer on the current window (split) by that buffer number

`:h :buffer`